# Cannot foreach through data context

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, ria, wcf-ria-services

i want to compare through 2 information, one is user input and second is admin ID in database. in my project, i'm using WCF Ria. i did created one auto-generated Domain Service Class and the code to retrieve everything in tblAdmin was auto-generated. i load the data in this way ::

```
        var context = new OrganizationContext();
        var x = context.tblAdmins;
        context.Load(context.GetTblAdminsQuery());
        cb1.ItemsSource = x;
```

it can load in this way, but i cannot get the x.adminID with this. so i tried this ::

```
        foreach (var admin in x)
        {
            cb1.Items.Add(admin.adminID);
        }
```

but failed... may i know is that possible to dig through the data without foreach or is there something wrong in my code ??

Comment: Is your tblAdmins an IEnumerable<T> ?

Comment: We have no way of telling the type of `x` given what you've shown. What is `OrganizationContext.tblAdmins`?

Comment: organization context is the file of domain service class

Comment: What's the exception you get?

Comment: i tried to make this and it's still no luck.. i'm total new to wcf, and i do it in this way         public IEnumerable<tblAdmin> GetAdmin()
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.tblAdmins.OrderBy(e => e.adminID);
        }

Comment: How is your code failing?  Are you getting any error messages?  Those will have clues as to the problem.

Comment: @David no error message, but just nothing display in cb1 when i use second code, i can get everything when i use first code but now i want adminID only

Comment: @SLim: When you debug into it, what is the state of the objects in the code?  What is `x`?  Is it enumerable?  Does it contain elements?  What is `admin` inside of the loop?  What is `cb1` before and after the call to `.Add()`?  We don't have nearly enough context to answer this for you.  We don't even know the types of your variables.

Comment: @David, context is OrganizationContext(Domain Service Class) with all the table. x is EntitySet<tblAdmin> .(system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.EntitySet<project1.web.tbladmin> and i found... x is null

Comment: @SLim: Those types don't mean much outside of your IDE.  And `OrganizationContext(Domain Service Class)` doesn't even look like valid C#.  If `x` is `null` then that would certainly explain why the `foreach` isn't running.  There are no items over which to enumerate.  Still, you need to do some basic debugging here.  We can't help you without any useful information.  You have all of the tools available to you, all we have is a code snippet that doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4731/discussion-between-slim-and-david)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that the context.Load call is asynchronous - to get the result you need to pass a callback and get your data there:

```
context.Load(context.GetTblAdminsQuery(), LoadCompleted, null);
```

and:

```
public void LoadCompleted(LoadOperation<YOUR_ENTITY_TYPE> op)
{
    foreach(var item in op.Entities)
    {
        //item is your entity, you can get item.adminID
    }
}
```

Comment: May i know do you know that how to store the specific line of item into generic list ? i tried with this :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018174/how-to-store-entities-context-query-object-into-generic-list but failed @.@