# How to store entities context query object into generic list?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, datacontext, domainservices

In [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013493/cannot-foreach-through-data-context/8015885#8015885), i successfully to dump the data into combo box with solution from  Leo but now, i want to get everything of specific user and store into generic list. i tried with this code but it's not working. May i know is there something wrong with my code ?

```
  var contexti = new OrganizationContext();
  //contexti.Load(contexti.GetAdminPassQuery(userName), LoadInfo, null);
  EntityQuery query = contexti.GetAdminPassQuery(userName);
  contexti.Load<tblAdmin>(query).Completed += (sender, args) =>
           {
                  List<AdminInfo> list = ((LoadOperation<tblAdmin>) sender).Entities.
                                         ToList();}
```

this is in the domain context.

```
    public IQueryable<tblAdmin>  GetAdminPass(string adminId)
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.tblAdmins.Where(e => e.adminID.Equals(adminId));
    }
```

this is the generic list store in helper folder

```
    public class AdminInfo
{
    public string AdminId { get; set; }
    public string AFirstName { get; set; }
    public string ALastName { get; set; }
    public string AEmail { get; set; }
    public string APassword { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you for reply

Comment: ToList -> ToList<AdminInfo>()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdminInfo is not the same type as tblAdmin so you need to manually create a new list:

```
contexti.Load<tblAdmin>(query).Completed += (sender, args) =>
{
    List<AdminInfo> list = new List<AdminInfo>();

    //for each entity returned, create a new AdminInfo and add it to the list
    foreach (var item in ((LoadOperation<Car>)sd).Entities)
    {
        list.Add(new AdminInfo(){ AdminId = item.AdminId, AFirtsName = item.FirstName /*other properties*/});
    }

}
```

Comment: Thx and again =D you helped me a lot... cheer and i hope i could sent you a beer =D